# Can HTMLbars be used without Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I've been looking for a while now, and every time HTMLbars is mentioned Ember is involved. The problem is I want to migrate from Handlebars to HTMLbars, however my project has a custom framework. If all that HTMLbars does it make it so the content is returned as HTML elements, rather than a string, why is it Ember exclusive, and has anyone found a way to work around that exclusivity.

Comment: here is an example of using it without ember https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars/blob/master/demos/compile-and-run.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can be used without Ember.js, you can analyze code in [demos](https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars/tree/master/demos) or you can dig into [tests in HTMLBars repository](https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars/tree/master/packages).

The most interesting fragment of code is:

```
var template = compiler.template(templateSpec);
var env = { dom: new DOMHelper(), hooks: hooks, helpers: {} };
var scope = hooks.createFreshScope();

hooks.bindSelf(env, scope, data);

var dom = render(template, env, scope, { contextualElement: output }).fragment;

output.innerHTML += '<hr><pre><code>' + JSON.stringify(data) + '</code></pre><hr>';
output.appendChild(dom);
```

Comment: That is a whole lot of ceremony for Text -> Dom templates. It is too bad it could not be used without the bindings/contexts so HTMLBars could be used with jQuery plugins that expect a Object -> Dom/HTML template function.